# Can't eliminate sine wave with notch filter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I writed this code to eliminate a sine wave from a audio file.

```
Fc = 40000;             %Sampling rate
F0 = 400;               %Notch frequency
Fs = Fc/2;              %Nyquist frequency
Fn = F0/Fs;             %Normalized frequency

r = 0.95;
num = [1 -2*cos(2*pi*Fn) 1];        % filter coefficients
den = [1 -2*r*cos(2*pi*Fn) r^2];    % filter coefficients

%Load original audio file
samples = [1, 5*Fc];
[clean_wav, Fc]=audioread('mustang.wav', samples);
originale_wav(:,2) = [];

%Add sine wave disturb
j = 1;
while j<(samples(2)+1),
  t(j) = j/Fc;
  j = j+1;
end; 
x=sin(2*pi*F0*t);
disturbed_wav = clean_wav' + x;

filtered_wav = filter(num,den, x);

soundsc(filtered_wav, Fc);
```

The filter dosent eliminate the sine wave at all. I've tried different implementation of the notch filter but it did not work anyway.
Could you please help me find where is the mistake?
Thanks for all answers.

Comment: I am not familiar with your method of determining the filter coefficients, but when looking at the frequency response using `freqz(num,den, [], Fc)` I see that your notch frequency is at about 800 Hz, instead of your required 400 Hz, which suggest that you are a factor 2 off in your `Fn`. `Fn=F0/Fc` seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In fact if i do as you said i get a significant attenuation of the sine wave but it does not eliminate it, and at high frequency i can't hear any attenuation. Is it normal?

Comment: Look at the frequency content of your signal, as demonstrated in my answer, this should help you in determining what frequencies you are removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the example below. It helps to look at the frequency content of your signal using `fft` before and after filtering. Then you can visualize clearly what is happening to your signal, what frequencies you are filtering.

```
% load a default sound
load handel.mat; % puts y and Fs in workspace
sound(y,Fs)

% Sample frequency and frequency to filter
%Fs = 8192; % from load handle.mat
F0 = 400; % frequency to filter

% time vector
t = (0:numel(y)-1).'/Fs;
% frequency vector for fft
f = 0:1/t(end):Fs;
% fft signal
Y = fft(y);

% add some sine wave with frequency F0 and small amplitude.
y_noise = y + 0.1*sin(2*pi*F0*t);

% listen to the sound
sound(y_noise, Fs)

% look at difference frequency content y and y_noise
Yn = fft(y_noise);

figure(2); clf;
plot(f,abs(Y),f,abs(Yn))


% filter
Wn = F0./Fs*2;
Q = 35;
[b,a] = iirnotch(Wn,Wn/Q);
y_filt = filter(b,a,y_noise);

% look at frequency response notch filter
freqz(b,a,[],Fs)

% fft to show frequency content filtered signal
Y_filt = fft(y_filter);

figure(3); clf;
plot(f,abs(Y),f,abs(Y_filt))
```

To illustrate, here is the frequency content of the signal I used, clearly a sharp peak at 400 Hz: 
[image: fft y]

After filtering, this high peak is clearly gone:

[image: fft y filter]

But when looking closer at frequencies you can see that you are also filtering frequencies around 400 Hz, which you can tune using the Q factor when using `iirnotch` (blue signal is fft of original sound, orange is the fft of the filtered signal).

[image]